# How do you list number 1-10 with something in front of it

Tags: python

I am trying to make a stage type game where the player collects characters using a random draw machine called "gacha". The player can buy a gacha by spending in-game currency earned by playing the game. I just started to make the game and I make it so the way the game runs the command

```
adventure()
```

and I defined "adventure()" as

```
def adventure():
    print(f'you are currentyly on stage {player_stage}')
    print('[a]play / [b]edit team / [c]change stage / [d]exit')
    print('player team:')
    for i,character in enumerate(player_team, 1):
        print(i, character)
    player_input = input('> ')
    if player_input == 'd':
        return (whatever I have to return after playing)
    elif player_input == 'c':
        change_stage()
```

Lets say the player is on stage 4-5(chapter 4, stage 5) and when the player wants to change the stage to re-play previous stages, I want the code to display

```
4-1 (available)
4-2 (available)
4-3 (available)
4-4 (available)
4-5 (available)
4-6 (unavailable)
4-7 (unavailable)
4-8 (unavailable)
4-9 (unavailable)
4-10 (unavailable)
```

because there are 10 stages per chapter. I have defined player_team as

```
player_team = [
    f'{Fore.WHITE}Academy Naruto{Style.RESET_ALL} [1 star]',
    f'{Fore.WHITE}1% Deku{Style.RESET_ALL} [1 star]',
    f'{Fore.WHITE}Academy Sakura{Style.RESET_ALL} [1 star]'
```

And i defined player_stage as

```
player_front_stage = 1
player_back_stage = 1
player_stage = f'{player_front_stage}-{player_back_stage}'
```

Front_stage meaning the chapter and back_stage meaning stage
I could  define change_stage() as

```
def change_stage():
    if player_front_stage == 1:
        if player_back_stage == 1:
            print('1-1 (available)')
            print('1-2 (unavailable)')
            print('1-3 (unavailable)')
            print('1-4 (unavailable)')
            print('1-5 (unavailable)')
            print('1-6 (unavailable)')
            print('1-7 (unavailable)')
            print('1-8 (unavailable)')
            print('1-9 (unavailable)')
            print('1-10 (unavailable)')
        elif player_back_stage == 2:
            print('1-1 (available)')
            print('1-2 (available)')
            print('1-3 (unavailable)')
            print('1-4 (unavailable)')
            print('1-5 (unavailable)')
            print('1-6 (unavailable)')
            print('1-7 (unavailable)')
            print('1-8 (unavailable)')
            print('1-9 (unavailable)')
            print('1-10 (unavailable)') 
        elif player_back_stage == 3:
            ... (keep going until 1-10 is available)
    elif player_front_stage == 2:
            ... (same thing as player_front_stage 1)
```

But it would be too long and I'm sure there would be some way to reduce this code like

```
check what stage player is on,
print the stages on that chapter only,
put available next to stages that are <= to player_back_stage,
put unavailable to rest.
```

if you need my full code

```
from colorama import Fore
from colorama import Style
def game():
    print('[he]list of commands')

    command_list = [
        '[help/he]list of commands',
        '[balance/ba] player balance',
        '[adventure/ad] go clear stagse'
    ]

    player_coin = 10000
    player_gem = 500

    player_front_stage = 1
    player_back_stage = 1
    player_stage = f'{player_front_stage}-{player_back_stage}'

    player_team = [
        f'{Fore.WHITE}academy naruto{Style.RESET_ALL} [1 star]',
        f'{Fore.WHITE}1% deku{Style.RESET_ALL} [1star]',
        f'{Fore.WHITE}Academy sakura{Style.RESET_ALL} [1 star]'
    ]

    def he():
        for i,command in enumerate(command_list, 1):
            print(i, command_list)

    def ba():
        print(f' player coin: {Fore.YELLOW}{player_coin}{Style.RESET_ALL}')
        print(f' player gem: {Fore.BLUE}{player_gem}{Style.RESET_ALL}')

    def change_stage():
        what do i put here

    def ad():
        print(f'스테이지 {player_stage}')
        print('[a]플레이 / [b]팀변경 / [c]스테이지 변경 / [d]나가기')
        print('플레이어 팀 :')
        for i,character in enumerate(player_team, 1):
            print(i, character)
        player_input = input('> ')
        if player_input == 'd':
            return
        elif player_input == 'c':
            change_stage()

    while True:
        player_input = input('> ')

        if player_input == 'he':
            he()

        elif player_input == 'ba':
            ba()
game()
```

Comment: Use for loop: `for i in range(0, 10): print(i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some sort of string formating like this:

```
def printOptions(front,back):
  for k in range(1,11):
     if k<=back:
       print('%s-%s (available)'%(front,back))
     else:
       print('%s-%s (unavailable)'%(front,back))
```

The %s inside the quotes are replaced with the values %(front,back) respectively.